# Assume an LP has 2 optimal solutions $u$ and $v$. Show for any t in [0,1] that $tu+(1-t)v$ is also optimal

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-geometry

Considering an LP with:

\begin{align}
&\text{max}\ \ c\cdot x \\
  &Ax\le b\\
& x\geq 0 \\
\end{align}

Assume this LP has two optimal solutions $u$ and $v$. Show for any $t \in [0,1]$ that $tu+(1-t)v$ is also an optimal solution. First show $tu-(1-t)v$ has the same value as $u$ in the objective function. Then show $tu+(1-t)v$ is feasible solution to the LP.

So I know since they're both optimal functions that means that $u$ and $v$ must have the same objective function value otherwise one isn't the optimal point. I don't know if it's a proof, but $tu+(1-t)v$ has to be feasible because it runs parallel to the points $u$ and $v$ which are both optimal so that means that $tu+(1-t)v$ is also optimal? But I don't think that's a sufficient proof if a proof at all.

We can show $tu+(1-t)v$ is feasible by $A(tu+(1-t)v)=A(tu+(1-t)v)=Atu+(1-t)Av \le bt+(1-t)b=b$ from the domain of x if it's in the epigraph of the function, but I don't know about showing $tu+(1-t)v$ as an optimal solution. I'd just say it is cause it runs parallel to $u$ and $v$, in the direction of the gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the objective value is optimal, notice $$c(tu+(1-t)v)=tcu+cv-tcv$$ We know $cu=cv$ since both $u, v$ are optimal. Therefore, $tcu+cv-tcv=cv$ so $tu+(1-t)v$ has an optimal objective value.

Comment: duh of course it's so obvious after you explained it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is true for any convex problem. It is true because the level sets of a convex
function are convex, and the set of minimisers is a level set.